# Converting to Base 26 in One Based mode

Tags: c#, converting

I needed to create a simple method that converts numbers in *Base 26* (`string`) using, as expected, letters from a to z.

But that's not all, this *Base 26* needs to be *One Based*. Which means that there is no representation for zero absolute value and there is a representation for 26 absolute value. Let me show a example:

In *Base 26* *Zero Based* the number 18252 will be represented like:

$$
(18252)_{10} = (BBAA)_{26}
$$

where `B == 1` and `A == 0`. But as an *One Based* I need to get:

$$
(18252)_{10} = (ZYZ)_{26}
$$

where `Y == 25` and `Z == 26`.

So I came up with this snippet:

```
var array = new List<int>();

var div = myNumber;
var getOne = 0;

while (div > 26)
{
    var value = div % 26;

    value -= getOne;

    if (value <= 0)
    {
        value += 26;
        getOne = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        getOne = 0;
    }

    array.Add(value);

    div = div / 26;
}

div -= getOne;

if (div > 0) array.Add(div);

var letters = array.Select(s => (char)('A' + s - 1)).Reverse().ToArray();

return new string(letters);
```

Now I wonder if there is a better way write this.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to get an excel column name from a number e.g.  1 => A, 2 => B, ... 26 => Z, 27 => AA, 28 => AB. Is this correct?  If so, are you happy with a solution that works as far as 16384 (the max number of columns in an Excel spreadsheet)?

Comment: Yes, can be like Excel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could slightly simplify the code as follows:

- Reduce the number of variables.
- Use the `LinkedList<T>` (and the `AddFirst` method) instead of the `List<T>` to eliminate reversion of array.
  *Alternatively you can use the `List<T>.Insert` method to achieve the same result.*

The code:

```
private static string ToBase26(int myNumber)
{
    var array = new LinkedList<int>();

    while (myNumber > 26)
    {
        int value = myNumber % 26;
        if (value == 0)
        {
            myNumber = myNumber / 26 - 1;
            array.AddFirst(26);
        }
        else
        {
            myNumber /= 26;
            array.AddFirst(value);
        }
    }

    if (myNumber > 0)
    {
        array.AddFirst(myNumber);
    }
    return new string(array.Select(s => (char)('A' + s - 1)).ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the number of variables, and use `LinkedList<T>` method to eliminate reversion, like this:

```
private static string ToBase26(int number)
{
    var list = new LinkedList<int>();
    list.AddFirst((number - 1) % 26);
    while ((number = --number / 26 - 1) > 0) list.AddFirst(number % 26);
    return new string(list.Select(s => (char)(s + 65)).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't even compile.

Comment: What errors are it throwing?

Comment: Try it yourself and see.

Comment: And please perform some tests before posting. For instance, make sure that this code returns `ZYZ` for `18252`.

Comment: Fixed, and edited.